# Sticky footer button for form is not shown when keyboard pops up

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a sticky footer button in a form component. When opening the keyboard this button should also be on top of the keyboard. I tried to use `KeyboardAvoidingView` in many ways but it didn't help.

My current code:

```
  //...
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Animated.View
      style={[styles.line, { left: this.state.progressBar }]}
    />
    <kHeader
      hasBorderBottom={false}
      left={
        <IconButton
          onPress={onPreviousStep}
          style={styles.backIcon}
          name="back"
          size={20}
        />
      }
    />
    <Animated.View
      style={[styles.body, { left: this.state.stepContainerPosition }]}>
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children[step], {
        afterSubmit: onNextStep,
        submittedFieldsWithErrors,
        updateFocus,
        shouldWaitAnimationToFocus: true,
      })}
    </Animated.View>

    <FooterButton
      caption={this.props.children[step].props.buttonLabel}
      onPress={this.onSubmit}
    />
  </View>
  //...


const FooterButton = ({ caption, onPress }) =>
  <View style={styles.footer}>
    <SomeButtonComponent
      caption={caption}
      type="primary"
      size="fullWidth"
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={onPress}
    />
  </View>;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 0.2,
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    position: 'absolute',
  },
});
```

Current behaviour when a keyboard is opened:

**Android**: The footer button is shown on top of the keyboard which is the expected behaviour. But when closing the splash screen is shown for a brief second where the keyboard was

**iOS**: The button is not shown anymore.

How can I achieve a sticky button on top of the keyboard?

Comment: can you show how and where have you used `KeyboardAvoidingView` ?

Comment: While you're adding more code, you'll find a lot of tips and examples here about how handling keyboard with RN. It really helped me to understand and find a better way to deal with it : https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580